# Как определить путь к выполняемой сборке?

Tags: c#

Есть проект, содержащий несколько сборок. Как во время выполнения программы из любой сборки определить полный путь к ней в файловой системе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Для большинства случаев достаточно воспользоваться свойством [**`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)
- В случае, если происходил так называемый `assembly shadow copying` *(например, при загрузке из байтстрима)*, то правильный путь после `shadow copying` можно получить через `new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`
- Подробнее про этот сценарий можете прочитать [**в разделе Remarks.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx)